# build.gradle error when coding "getting started" template in VS Code for wpilib

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I've been attempting to program a basic robot for my FRC team, and to do so I've been using WPILib's guide for the FRC robot.

I've used the [getting started](https://docs.wpilib.org/en/stable/docs/zero-to-robot/step-4/creating-benchtop-test-program-cpp-java.html) guide, and have loaded up the program.

build.gradle is throwing an error, where it is stating `Unresolved dependency:Junit:Junit:4.12 Java(0) [1, 1]` twice.

The only error shown in the code is on this line:

```
import edu.wpi.first.gradlerio.deploy.roborio.RoboRIO
```

The only edits I've made to the program are
One: adding two new motors because our drive base has two motors on each side
Two: changing some of the naming of the motors and such to remove the `m_` at the start of their name, as my naming convention is different for how I program

I have no clue how to fix this, and I don't want it to mess up anything. Any help would be very appreciated,
-Kai